# prepared statements are not inserted

Tags: oracle, select, insert, jdbc, prepared-statement

i am new to JDBC and trying following code. Could not find the error in it

```
try{     
        Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon();
        stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into create_request values((select count(reqno) from create_request)+1,?,?,?,?,?");
        stmt.setString(1,obj_Leaverequest.getUser_name());
        stmt.setString(2,obj_Leaverequest.getLeave_Type());
        stmt.setInt(3,obj_Leaverequest.getLeave_Units());
        stmt.setString(4,obj_Leaverequest.getLeave_Reason());
        stmt.setString(5,"pending");
        count=stmt.executeUpdate();
        if(count>0){
            status=true;
        }
    }
```

Getters are working fine, i could print their values . i guess i am wrong with the query.Please point out my mistake. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you inserting a question mark into the table? ifso add '' around the ? eg '?'. You have to tell Oracle it's a string. Not used to work with Java so could be wrong.

Comment: @Munchi no i guess , no need of adding quotes . Anyhow thanks for your attempt :)

Comment: 1) What are you trying to do? 2) What is the structure of the table? 3) What error do you get?

Comment: @Munchi For your future reference, the '?' are binds

Comment: So he messed up with his query? He got 1 value and trying to insert 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the columns and use SELECT:

```
"insert into create_request (col1,col2,etc..col6) 
select ?,?,?,?,?, count(reqno) +1 from create_request"
```

Just make sure the values and columns match.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have forgotten a ')'.

try this:

```
stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into create_request values((select count(reqno) from create_request)+1),?,?,?,?,?");
```

Comment: @rheddeg nope :( it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

@Krish: If your Getters are correct, then can you try below options:

a.) Try using

`stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into create_request values((select count(reqno) from  create_request)+1,?,?,?,?,?)");`

b.) In case the above one does not work, try running your insert query in database directly with the approprate values for the bind variables.

Please let us know if it works.

Thanks

Vishad